# Call php file from metro application

Tags: php, authentication, microsoft-metro

I am currently in the process of creating a windows 8 application using C# and I need to access a php file from a website which has a function loginUser($userParam, $passParam) that handles user login into a database. Any hints on how this can be done? Should I use HttpRequest or is there another method?

Comment: Are you trying to access the PHP file contents or to use the results that the PHP script produces when it is executed?

Comment: If you're making a web request then it doesn't matter that the server-side technology is PHP or what any function name therein is called.  You're not calling the PHP code, you're making an HTTP request to the resulting web page.  A Google search for something like "WinRT Http Request" seems to find some good information...

Comment: I want to use parameters that a user enters from the application and use the php script to login the user using these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$userParam` and `$passParam` via GET or POST query and call this function in your PHP script, like

```
echo loginUser($_REQUEST['userParam'], $_REQUEST['passParam']);
```

You can make GET or POST request with WebRequest, for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx